# Wiring up event handler of object in class to a method in the same class

Tags: powershell

I have coded a small class which has several Windows.Forms objects in it.  I want to attach some code to the $Cancel button event handler which closes the form.  The following code below works:

```
Class MyObject
{
    $Form = (New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form)
    $DataGridView = (New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView)
    $Cancel = (New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button)
    $Save = (New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button)

    # Setup all my controls here and add them to $Form...

    $this.AddEventHandlers()
}

hidden [void] AddEventHandlers ()
{
    # Closes form.
    $this.Cancel.Add_Click( { $this.Parent.Close() } )
}
```

I initially tried to wire up the event code to a method of an object in my class (`$this.Form.Close()`), but there seemed to be a context issue and the event handler code seemed unaware of anything in my class.  When I changed it to `$this.Parent.Close()`, it started working.  The event handler's `$this` seems to be scoped to the button itself, but I want to be able to get back at my class.

Is there a way I can point the event handler to a method in my class, and therefore, get at all the objects in my class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case this ever interests anyone, I've arrived at a solution.

To ensure I always have a reference back to the instance of my object that the event handling is originating from, I've added a member (property) to each object I want to make sure can talk to the instance, and pass through a reference to the instance.  So, for the Cancel button, I've done this:

```
Class MyObject
{
    $Form = (New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form)
    $DataGridView = (New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView)
    $Cancel = (New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button)
    $Save = (New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button)

    # Setup all my controls here and add them to $Form...

    # Add property new property and set it to a reference to $this instance.
    Add-Member -InputObject $this.Cancel -MemberType NoteProperty -Name MyObject -Value $this

    $this.AddEventHandlers()
}

hidden [void] AddEventHandlers ()
{
    # Closes form; now we have all methods and objects from instance at our disposal.
    $this.Cancel.Add_Click( { $this.MyObject.Form.Close() } )
}
```

With the .MyObject property now coming off the button, I can call a method off the class to do the work.  In this case, I decided to simply call the .Close method off the $this.MyObject.Form property as it was straight-forward.  I could just as easily call a method off my instance if it were required.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `param($sender,$e)` to your event handler to receive these objects. This will allow you to access $sender (your button) inside the handler. You can then call [FindForm()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.findform) to locate the form containing the button. Careful with .Parent as that is the immediate parent which may be a different object than the top level form if you have any panels, etc.

```
    # Closes form.
    $this.Cancel.Add_Click( {
        param($sender, $e)
        $form = $sender.FindForm()
        if($null -ne $form){
            $form.Close()
        }
    } )
```

If you want to setup methods in you class you can do this as well though I have only been ever able to use static methods to do so. This adds the problem of only being able to access static properties and methods though.

```
#Will error when called, cannot call instance value from static
static [void] CloseMe(){
    $form.Close()
}

#removing static isn't better as it will now error here   
#method cannot be found
$button.Add_MouseClick({
    CloseMe($this, $_)
})

#but you can use statics
$button.Add_MouseClick({
    [MyObject]::CloseMe($this, $_)
})

#will work though its essentially the same as placing it all in the handler
static [void] CloseMe($sender, $e){
    $f = $sender.FindForm()
    if($null -ne $f){
        $f.Close()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input and caveats.  My essential question remains unanswered, though: is it possible for me to wire up the event handler to a method in my class?  I am not simply looking to target the form, I am looking to get back at the class itself; it looks like I'm still going to have the same problem here.  Or am I missing something?  Thanks.

Comment: In order to get to the encapsulating class itself, I think you will have to use static properties or methods. The form is passed to the event handler so we can access it but I cannot figure out a way to reach the encapsulating class.

Comment: Thanks for your input.  I've actually figured out at least one way to do it.  See the answer I've submitted.